# How to reload datatable from MVC model after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a datatable initialize from MVC model that load to view page

```
@using model
<table id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      @foreach item in model {
       <tr>
        <td>item.Name</td>
        <td>item.Pos</td>
       </tr>
      }
</table>
```

in script I have

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#example').DataTable({
"scrollY": "50vh",
"scrollCollapse": true,
});
$('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
});
```

Is there any way I can reload my table after an ajax call?

Comment: What's the "ajax call" doing?  You can return your table as a partial from that ajax call, or to keep single-responsibility make a 2nd ajax call to get just the table, reset the HTML and re-call `.DataTable` - alternatively have datatable get its data via ajax

Comment: ajax to update an attribute from that table, currently I'm doing location.reload(), but I tried to find a solution to only reload a table itself, not the whole page.

Comment: You could also update the datatable's data with the new attribute

Comment: could you please give me an example? I tried to called action in controller that initialize my model, but it doesn't reload the table itself.